# How to allow param with curly braces in Url when using WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am getting IllegalArgumentException
"Not enough variable values available to expand 'email'" when calling an endpoint with curly braces in the url. I don't want to encode it since the endpoint is throwing 500 after the url is ecoded.

```
   @Override
    public Mono<UserInfoByEmailV2> findByEmail(String env, String email) {
        webClient = getTokenAndSetupWebClient(env, webClient, log);
       // Param email here is like {{test}}@test.com
        return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/user/?email={email}")
                .replaceQueryParam("email", email)
                .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(UserInfoByEmailV2.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer;

```
    @Override
    public Mono<UserInfoByEmailV2> findByEmail(String env, String email) {
        webClient = getTokenAndSetupWebClient(env, webClient, log);
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("/user?email={test}", email)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(UserInfoByEmailV2.class);
    }
```